# How to get the User Principle ID based on the Email Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile

How to get the User Principle ID based on the Email Id provide in the textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the User details using user Login Name by using REST API URL like below:

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='<login name>'
```

Where you have to replace the user's login name.

As you have user's email address you can construct (hard codes) the login name using email address. And for that you just need the format of login name for your SharePoint site which you can get by hitting below URL in browser and search for `LoginName`:

```
https://<site url>/_api/Web/CurrentUser?$select=Id,LoginName
```

The Login Name will be in format something like : `i:0%23.f|membership|ganesh.sanap@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`

Everything after `membership|` is email address of user. So using email address you can build the login name string like this and use it in the first REST API above to get the User Principle ID.

This is a work around for your scenario. Maybe you can get another better way. But you can try this for now.